# On startup I have two network configurations, but not honoring settings

Tags: networking, network-manager

On Ubuntu 18.10 I have an ethernet connection on interface `enp3s0`. On startup it uses DHCP, but DNS doesn't work. When setting it to static and applying, it works. But on reboot the same thing happens.

Two options are available in the network system tray icon menu on boot:

- enp3s0 (the broken ephemeral active one I presume)
- Wired Connection 1 (the one I create and save)

When I choose "Wired Connection 1" in the NetworkManager tray menu it connects and works, and then the breaking one disappears.

Checking in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` only "Wired Connection 1" shows with the correct settings.

Where does the intruding DHCP enp3s0 one come from on boot, and why doesn't the system honor the saved settings on startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something outside NetworkManager is configuring the device. NetworkManager notices that, and generates an in-memory profile that reflects what was externally configured. Note that in this case, NetworkManager does not actually do anything with the device. It just pretends, something is configured.

The solution is to not externally configure the device before starting NetworkManager. Alternatively, manually activate the profile you want and NetworkManager will take over (`nmcli connection up ...`).

Comment: How can I determine what is setting it up before NM?

Comment: It was aoetools that I used one time a couple of months back. It had an initramfs script enabling DHCP very early on in the startup. Removing that and rebuilding initramfs and grub fixed my issue.